# Learning CFEngine from 3.5 manual and operating in a 3.7 enviornment

Tags: syntax-error, cfengine

**Edited 4/15/2016
Using the absolute path to reference the stdlib got my promise to execute, now the errors I'm experiencing changed. See last code block for that error output.

Using [this reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=jbKNAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=cfengine%203.5%20%20learning&source=bl&ots=kd1KmHbJg4&sig=IjTT1LM6Kpwnj-A5PqrvExSJGdM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU6PH49InMAhUB_2MKHfIrCE8Q6AEISzAI#v=onepage&q=cfengine%203.5%20%20learning&f=false) material for CFEngine 3.5 (it's what i've got from da boss) but I'm writing promises for a 3.8 environment. This is leading me to improperly using the stdlib and have poor syntax.

What I'm looking at now has the following promise and error output when invoked.

Promise:

```
{
        inputs =>
                 # COPBL/Custom libraries.  Eventually this should use wildcards.
                 #@(cfengine_stdlib.inputs)
                 { "/var/cfengine/inputs/lib/stdlib.cf" }; #Edited this line 4/15/2016

        bundlesequence => { "configfiles" };
}

bundle agent configfiles
{
    vars:
        # Files to edit
        "files[sysctl]" string => "/etc/sysctl.conf";
        "files[sshd]" string => "/etc/ssh/sshd_config";
        "files[inittab]" string => "/etc/inittab";

        # Sysctl variables to set
        "sysctl[net.ipv4.ip_forward]" string => "0";
        "sysctl[net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter]" string => "1";
        "sysctl[net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route]" string => "0";
        "sysctl[kernel.sysrq]" string => "0";
        "sysctl[kernel.core_uses_pid]" string => "1";
        "sysctl[net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies]" string => "1";
        "sysctl[net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables]" string => "0";
        "sysctl[net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables]" string => "0";
        "sysctl[net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables]" string => "0";

        # SSHD configuration to set
        #
        "sshd[Protocol]" string => "2";
        "sshd[SyslogFacility]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[LoginGraceTime]" string => "2m";
        "sshd[PermitRootLogin]" string => "no";
        "sshd[StrictModes]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[MaxAuthTries]" string => "3";
        "sshd[RSAAuthentication]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[PubkeyAuthentication]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[PasswordAuthentication]" string => "no";
        "sshd[ChallengeResponseAuthentication]" string => "no";
        "sshd[GSSAPIAuthentication]" string => "no";
        "sshd[UsePAM]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[X11Forwarding]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[UsePrivilegeSeparation]" string => "yes";
        "sshd[UseDNS]" string => "no";


    methods:
        "sysctl" usebundle => edit_sysctl;
        "sshd" usebundle => edit_sshd;
        "inittab" usebundle => edit_inittab;
}

bundle agent edit_inittab
{
    files:
        "$(configfiles.files[inittab])"
        handle => "inittab_set_initdefault",
        comment => "Default runmode=5",
        create => "false",
        edit_defaults => backup_timestamp,
        edit_line => set_colon_field("id","2","5");
}




bundle agent edit_sshd
{
    files:
        "$(configfiles.files[sshdconfig])"
        handle => "edit_sshd",
        comment => "Set desired sshd_config parameters",
        edit_line => set_config_values("configfiles.sshd"),
        classes => if_repaired("restart_sshd");

    commands:
        restart_sshd&!no_restarts::
        "/etc/init.d/sshd reload"
        handle => "sshd_restart",
        comment => "Restart sshd if the configuration file was modified";

    services:
        "ssh"
        service_policy => "start";
}



bundle agent edit_sysctl
{
    files:
        "$(configfiles.files[sysctl])"
            handle => "edit_sysctl",
            comment => "Make sure sysctl.conf contains desired configuration",
            create => "true",
            edit_line => set_variable_values("configfiles.sysctl"),
            classes => if_repaired("sysctl_modified");

    commands:
        sysctl_modified&!no_restarts::
            "/sbin/sysctl -p"
                handle => "reload_sysctl",
                comment => "Make sure new sysctl settings are loaded";
}
```

error output:

```
inputs]# cf-agent --no-lock --inform --file ./setting_configs.cf
   error: Promised to edit '$(configfiles.files[sshdconfig])', but file does not exist
   error: Method 'edit_sshd' failed in some repairs
```

I've confirmed that the sshd_config file is in place. Can't figure out why cfEngine doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using bad variable names; tried calling "sshdconfigs" when it should have been simply "sshd"